Defined many-to-many with Association table in SQLAlchemy
Updating with a more complete example
I've seen many solutions, but I still can't get this to work.
I have
class ModuleGroupMember(ModelBase):
    __tablename__ = 'module_group_member'
    pk = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    module_pk = mapped_column(Integer, ForeignKey('module.pk'))
    module_group_pk = mapped_column(Integer, ForeignKey('module_group.pk'))

class Module(ModelBase):
    __tablename__ = 'module'
    pk = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = mapped_column(String)
    groups = relationship("Module_Group", secondary="module_group_member", back_populates="modules")

class ModuleGroup(ModelBase):
    __tablename__ = 'module_group'
    pk = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    description = mapped_column(String)
    is_active = mapped_column(Boolean)
    name = mapped_column(String)
    modules = relationship("Module", secondary="module_group_member", back_populates="groups")

There are all in separate files, Module.py, ModuleGroup.py, and ModuleGroupMember.py, that are in a package called root.db.models.  I have an __init__.py like this
from .Module import Module
from .Module_Group import ModuleGroup
from .Module_Group_Member import ModuleGroupMember

metadata = ModelBase.metadata

def create_tables():
    metadata.create_all(engine)


def drop_tables():
    metadata.drop_all(engine)

It's not clear to me if the secondary parameter is the table name or class name, but I've tried both.
When I run create_all(), the tables are not getting created.  Here's what I'm running.  Note that I import everything from root.db.models
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, URL
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, DeclarativeBase

from root.db.models import create_tables, Module, drop_tables

url = URL.create(
    drivername="postgresql",
    username="postgres",
    password="postgres",
    host="localhost",
    database="flask_test"
)
engine = create_engine(url, echo=True)


class ModelBase(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


metadata = ModelBase.metadata
drop_tables()
create_tables()

with sessionmaker(bind=engine)() as session:
    with session.begin():
        session.add(Module(name="Module1"))
        session.commit()


I get the following error when trying to add a row in the Module table
    raise NameError( NameError: Module 'Module_Group' has no mapped classes registered under the name '_sa_instance_state'

Running this code, I get Module_Group not defined;  After fixing it (it should be ModueGroup), the code runs without error. Please review the example code and ensure that it is a [mre].

"Not sure if it has to do with the order of the loading or something like that". I would guess this is it, the easiest fix is to just import all your models before you make the create_all call in your code, after which you might get what @snakecharmerb mentions

Edited with a more completed reproducible example.  It's not clear to me where Module_Group should be ModuleGroup, but I've tried other combinations and still can't get it to work.

groups = relationship("Module_Group", secondary="module_group_member", back_populates="modules") probably here
